# Type conversion

Tags: c, pointers, int, type-conversion

Can someone please tell me what do these lines of code do

```
*(a++)  = (int)((value >> 16) & 0xFF) ;
*(a++)  = (int)((value >> 8) & 0xFF) ;  
*(a++)  = (int)((value & 0xFF)) ;
```

I understand that it checks the value, if it is much greater than 16 it converts it to type int and if it is much smaller than 8 does the same. But what does the
 `& 0xFF` and  `*(a++)` do?

Comment: "_much_ smaller" is not a term understandable by computers. That's your hint for understanding `<<` doesn't mean much smaller!

Comment: programming symbols are different than mathimatical symbols. basically in each language every symbol can mean something very unrelated to what it means in another language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that it checks the value

It doesn't check anything, it's not like the `<<` symbol in math which means "much smaller". To break down this line:

```
*(a++)  = (int)((value >> 16) & 0xFF);
```

- (`>>`) [shifts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Arithmetic_shift) `value` 16 times to the right
- (`&`) [ands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_and#AND) the result with `0xFF`, thereby discarding everything to the left
- Stores the result at the address pointed by `a`
- Increments the pointer, making `a` point to some "next" element

Answer (score 1):

(value>>16)

No it is not much greater.

```
It is shift right by 16 bits.
```

But dividing it by 2 exatly 16 times makes it much smaller than before.

```
val&0xff makes a solution if it is divisible by 256. For example: if val&0xff is different than zero, than it is not divisible by 256
```

Answer (score 1):

```
*(a++)  = (int)((value >> 16) & 0xFF) ;
```

is like:

```
aIntValue = value/65536;
aIntBalue = a%256;
```

---

```
*(a++)  = (int)((value >> 8) & 0xFF) ;
```

is like:

```
aIntValue = value/256;
aIntValue = a%256;
```

---

```
*(a++)  = (int)((value & 0xFF)) ;
```

is like:

```
aIntValue = a%256;
```

At the end of the code, either code assign the aIntValut to the value pointed to the pointer 'a' and next the pointer is moved to the next element.

Comment: but a is a pointer so a=value/65536 is invalid. it should be *a

Comment: `value` is not `a` so the different statements in your example are not similar or equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the comments: I have correct the code, I was focus on explain bit math and I choice unlucky variable name (same name of the pointer XP )

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
char data[10];

uint32_t value = 0x61626364; // 'abcd'

char *a = data;
*(a++) = (int)((value >> 24) & 0xFF);
*(a++) = (int)((value >> 16) & 0xFF);
*(a++) = (int)((value >> 8) & 0xFF);
*(a++) = (int)(value & 0xFF);
*(a++) = ':';
*((uint32_t *)a) = value;
a+=4;
*(a++) = 0;

printf("%s\n", data);
```

I get (on my intel box, which is a little endian system):

```
abcd:dcba
```

So this is ensuring that the bytes of an integer are in an platform-independent form (choosing big endian as the byte format).

Now, for:

```
*(a++) = (int)((value >> 16) & 0xFF);
```

we have:

```
0x61626364 -- value
0x00006162 -- value >> 16 : shifted 2 bytes
0x00000062 -- (value >> 16) & 0xFF : last byte only
```